# Call a Hub method from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want to call a hub method from my aspx.cs file and I don't know how. I've already searched for answers and nothing works, this seems to work for others, but it's also not working

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.All.brod("notify called");
```

This the caller method:

```
public void Notify()
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
    context.Clients.All.brod("notify called");
}
```

This is the js method for displaying:

```
chat.client.brod = function (msg) {
                                     messages.append('<li>'+msg+' </li>');
                                  }
```

So, how to call a Hub method from C#?

Please help...

Comment: thank's for your reply , but it's also not working ...

Comment: "not working" really doesn't give much information. What *is* happening, compared with what you expected to happen? What diagnostic steps have you performed so far, and what did they reveal?

Comment: Thank's For your answer , actually nothing happen when i click on the button ,
i tried an exemple of code like " textbox1.text="abcd" " but and nothing happen
it's look like the problem is in the click_event ,please help :/

Comment: It's Working ,I Button Control Had ~ OnClientClick="return false;"  ~
this is why the code wasn't working , Thank You Everyone !